# I need to redirect a vanity url to a page of the same name inside a directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

A typical .htaccess redirect looks like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /old-page /directory/new-page
```

I am trying to redirect only a specific, root level page (which doesnt exist), to a page with the same name, but in a different directory- and am getting a loop (because apache is seeing "oh that ends in /whatever, lets redirect it again). Here's my redirect example, does this have an obvious problem?

```
RedirectMatch 301 /specific-page-name /directory/specific-page-name
```

The purpose of this is to add a UTM code to a page when it gets typed in from some physical marketing media (flyer, card, etc) to give them an easy to type url, and get analytics that let us know that they are coming to the site from a specific non-web source.

Comment: You need to fix your regex pattern `/specific-page-name` also matchs the destination path `/directory/specific-page-name` . Use this pattern `^/specific-page-name` to fix it

Comment: I appreciate your input, and had originally tagged it with regex, as I assumed it might be relevant here, however the regex tag was immediately removed by another contributor. I'm not sure why my post got downvoted.

Comment: I am not the downvoter.  I added the regex tag back because it's a regex related question. Fixing the regex and clearing your browser cache should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to mark your comment as the answer but I may not be able to because of my newbie status. That was the issue and it works properly now.